# Computing the reduced $K$-theory of $\mathbb CP^n$ using AHSS

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, vector-bundles, spectral-sequences, topological-k-theory

I'm studying Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence from some slides, a bit hard to follow as they are a collage of pages from various books and papers, filled with writings and deletions made by hand by my teacher.

In particular, I'm trying to piece together the calculation of $\tilde{K^i}(\mathbb CP^n)$.

A theorem (that holds replacing $\mathbb CP^n$ with any space) says that the groups $E_2^{p,q}$ in the second page of the AHSS for $\tilde{K^*}(\mathbb CP^n)$ are described as: $$E_2^{p,q}=\tilde{H^p}(\mathbb CP^n,\tilde{K^q}(S^0)).$$

Moreover I know that:

- $\tilde{K^q}(S^0)=\mathbb Z$ if $q=2k$ for an integer $k$, otherwise $\tilde{K^q}(S^0) =0$;
- $\tilde{H^p}(\mathbb CP^n, G)=G$ if $p=2k$ for a (strictly) positive integer $k$, and $\tilde{H^p}(\mathbb CP^n, G)=0$ otherwise.

Hence at the second page the situation should be the following:

- $E^{p,q}_2=\mathbb Z$ if $p=2k$, for a (strictly) positive integer $k$, and $q=2k'$, for an integer $k'$;
- $E^{p,q}_2=0$ otherwise.

At this point, with methods I cannot replicate, it is computed the page at infinity of our spectral sequence, described by these drawings.

[image]

*First doubt.* In the image above, the first drawing depicts exactly the situation I described for the second page, in the latter two points, but the rightmost drawing suggests that the page at infinity is a bounded version of the second page: in particular, $E_\infty^{p,q}=0$ if $|q|\gt 2n$, and there seems to be an upper bound also on $p$.

Now, I know that the subsequent pages of the spectral sequence are computed in this way. Let $E_1:=\bigoplus_{p,q} E_1^{p,q}$ and $d_1:E_1\to E_1$ be the differential homomorphism. Then $E_2:=ker(d_1)/im(d_1)$, and on this new (bigraded) abelian group we can define a differential $d_2:E_2\to E_2$, and so on until the situation stabilizes. Plus I know that, in the case of the AHSS, the $p,q$-component of the differential $d_{n+1}$ is a homomorphism $d_{n+1}^{p,q}:E_{n+1}^{p,q}\to E_{n+1}^{p+n+1,q-n}$; hence I think that $E_2^{p,q}$ should be equal to $ker(d_{n+1}^{p,q})/im(d^{p-n-1,q+n}_{n+1})$. However looking at the grid drawn above it is clear that, for any $n\gt 0$, if $E_{n+1}^{p,q}=\mathbb Z$ then both the domain of $d^{p-n-1,q+n}_{n+1}$ and the codomain of $d_{n+1}^{p,q}$ are zero, so that $E_{n+2}^{p,q}=E_{n+1}^{p,q}$.

Therefore my doubt is: how come the page at infinity is not equal to the second page, but is bounded? Since by the reasoning above, I would say that the pages stabilize already from the second one.

*Second doubt.* If the page at infinity was bounded like in the rightmost drawing above, it would mean that any group $\tilde{K^i}(\mathbb CP^n)$ has a filtration of the form: $$\cdots\to 0\to \mathbb Z\to\cdots\to\mathbb Z\to 0\to\cdots,$$ where the central dots substitute (say $N_i$) copies of $\mathbb Z$, and the external dots substitute zeros. What do I know from such a filtration? Can I say that $\tilde{K^i}(\mathbb CP^n)\cong \mathbb Z^{N_i}$? In the slides it seems so, but there are vague mentions to extension problems that are not explained.

I hope I have been clear in stating my issues, thanks for your patience.

**PS:** the uncut version of the image above, with computation of the $K$-theory.

[image]

Comment: I haven't read the whole thing yet, but you've forgotten that $H^k(\mathbb{C}P^n) = 0$ for $k > 2n$.

Comment: @J126 that would make sense, but Yiannis Loizides in his notes on AHSS (notes here: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://math.gmu.edu/~yloizide/Atiyah-Hirzebruch.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwigluL-j5yEAxXn3AIHHYeCCTYQFnoECBEQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0t06kvWHzXJlB0C17eH0Bo) doesn't mention the $2k$ bound in example 3.3. Could it be because he's using the reduced version $\tilde{H^*}$?

Comment: The notes are wrong. Since $\mathbb{C}P^n$ is a cell complex with no cells above dimension $2n$, it cannot have nonzero singular cohomology groups above that dimension.

Comment: The reduced cohomology only removes the $\mathbb{Z}$ at $H^0$. All other groups are unaffected by reduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the cohomology groups $H^k(\mathbb{C}P^n, \mathbb{Z})$ are $\mathbb{Z}$ for $k = 0, 2, 4, \ldots, 2n$ and are $0$ otherwise. So, the $E_2$ page is bounded.

Next, the degree of the differential on the $E_k$ page is $(k, k - 1)$. Since $E_2^{p, q}$ is only nonzero when both $p$ and $q$ are even, the differential will always miss the nonzero groups. That's because either $p + k$ or $q + k - 1$ will be odd for each $k$.

Thus the $E_\infty$ page is the same as the $E_2$ page.

Also, you'll find that $K^0(\mathbb{C}P^n) = \mathbb{Z}^{n + 1}$, which certainly has a filtration of the type you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, it is all clear until the last period; does that period mean that also the writings of my teacher (in the image I added to the post) are wrong?

Comment: Plus I'd like to understand this. It is ok that $\tilde{K^1}(\mathbb CP^n)=0$ for $i$ odd, because in the grid the diagonals defined by $p+q=i$, for $i$, odd are all zero, and I imagine that a group with a filtration made only by zeros must be zero. Instead the diagonals such that $p+q$ is even are sequence of copies of $\mathbb Z$ of variable length, as I described in the question. So I'd say that if an abelian group has a filtration of the form described in the question (for any $N_i$), then the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, is it right?

Comment: I forgot to include the exponent on the $\mathbb{Z}$. I fixed it now. Yes, $K^1(\mathbb{C}P^n) = 0$ for the reason you stated.